# Difference between 平気, 冷静, and 穏やか

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know the difference between 平気, 冷静, and 穏やか.
They mean "calm" but what is the difference between them ?

> 案外本当は**平気**なんじゃないの‌  I guess that means you're not that bothered by it
>   after all?‌
>
> **冷静**に返されオレは言葉を詰まらせた。  She returned my words calmly and shut me up.
>
> なんていうオレの**穏やか**な気持ちはすぐに消し飛ばされてしまった。  My tranquility and peace was suddenly
>   interrupted.

From what I guess,

平気 : not to be bothered

冷静: to remain cool

穏やか : related to peace of mind

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically right.

- **平気**: antonym for "damaged", "dangerous", "ill", "negatively affected", etc.
- **冷静**: antonym for "lost one's cool", "short-tempered", "angry", etc.
- **穏やか**: antonym for "anxious", "restless", "bothered", etc.